# Issue with 301 redirect to Index page only

Tags: htaccess, html, url, php, 301-redirect

I have a bunch of 301 redirects in my `.htaccess` for old pages, which work great.

But a problem that's been plaguing me for years is that there's a lot of links out there to my old index page (`index.html`).  I want to redirect them to the new `index.php`, so as to save link juice etc. (if that's still how it works?)

The problem is, if I make a redirect from `index.html` to `index.php` it works **fine** for my main website... **but** it also affects the other websites (separate URLs) which are running from subfolders on the same server. It makes the index pages of all the other websites redirect to the main one too.

How can I write a redirect that only affects the index page of the main domain, without affecting the other sites? My obvious first thought was to use two absolute URLs, but apparently that's a no-no?

Comment: It would help if you added what you have tried and what your existing redirects are like. For instance, are you using mod_alias `Redirect` (`RedirectMatch`) or mod_rewrite `RewriteRule`?

Comment: What I tried before was redirect 301

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your "other websites" are using different domains/hosts then you can check the `HTTP_HOST` before redirecting. The same as you would do for a canonical www redirect.

However, this does require the use of mod_rewrite. Assuming `example.com` is your main domain, then you can do something like the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=301,L]
```

What this does is... for all requests that match `/index.html` and the *host* matches `example.com` (or `www.example.com`) then 301 redirect to `example.com/` (or `www.example.com/`).

Note that this simply redirects to `/` and allows mod_dir to fetch the required `DirectoryIndex` (ie. `index.php`). If you really want to be explicit and redirect to `index.php` (not recommended, unless that is what you are currently doing) then include the full *substitution* `/index.php`.

The `(www\.)?` (making www optional) would be unnecessary if you have a canonical redirect in place.

If you are currently using `Redirect` (or `RedirectMatch`), part of mod_alias, then you would ideally convert these to mod_rewrite as well. Otherwise, be careful of any conflicts. mod_alias will run *after* mod_rewrite, despite the apparent order of the directives in `.htaccess`.

> My obvious first thought was to use two absolute URLs, but apparently that's a no-no?

It's only a "no-no" in so far as the relevant Apache directives don't allow you to specify an absolute URL as the *source*. They expect a URL-path only. The *host* part of the source URL is separated out. However, an absolute *target* URL (or *substitution* in mod_rewrite terminology) is perfectly OK.

> ...other websites (separate URLs) which are running from subfolders

Running separate websites in *subdirectories* off the main domain is not ideal, unless they are closely related. Because `.htaccess` files are inherited along the *filesystem path* you can have conflicts.

Comment: Wow.. thank you for this incredible, detailed and informative answer!!!  I'm just trying it... seems to be working!!! =O

Comment: Yes, rerouting to www.example.com is perfect.  You're right.. I don't need to redirect to index.php explicitly.. this totally fixes it :)

Comment: Thank you so much!  I think I've been plagued by this for like 10 years haha..